# Loki's Trickery card rss

Tags: blood-rage

Suppose that players A, B, and C are in battle. 
Players A and B each play the Loki's Trickery card (If you lose, steal 1 rage from the winning player ). 
Player C wins the battle, but he has only 1 rage 
What happens now ?
Which player will steal the 1 rage from Player C?

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on who started the pillage.**

Starting with the pillaging player, go in turn order. The first player executes their Loki's Trickery effect and steals a rage. The second player now cannot do so.

[Source](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20734221#20734221).